# Transferring a vector<shared_ptr<T>> by reference without bypassing shared semantics

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

I have a class which contains a `vector<shared_ptr<T>>`:

```
using SharedItems = std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Item>>;

class LargeLift
{
public:
    SharedItems& getItems()
    {
        return _items;
    }

    void setSharedItems(SharedItems& items)
    {
        _items = items;
    }

private:
    SharedItems _items;
};
```

I then do the following:

```
LargeLift b;
{
    LargeLift a;
    // Gets populated

    SharedItems& items = a.getItems();
    b.setSharedItems(items);
}

// Variable a is now out of scope

SharedItems& items2 = b.getItems();
```

**Is the last line valid, given `a` has gone out of scope?**

Comment: @Yksisarvinen so in the above code, the last line would be unsafe because a has gone out of scope. So I should make the getter() return by value?

Comment: `a` has not gone out of scope in the example above

Comment: @Eric I am saying it has, to assist my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As written, your code is safe - nothing has gone out of scope.

In this example, `a` *does* go out of scope, but things are still safe:

```
LargeLift b;
{
    LargeLift a;
    // Gets populated

    SharedItems& items = a.getItems();

    //give b its own copy
    b.setSharedItems(items);
}

// safe, because b owns its own copy
SharedItems& items2 = b.getItems();
```

In this example, they are not safe:

```
SharedItems* p_items;

LargeLift b;
{
    LargeLift a;
    // Gets populated

    items = &a.getItems();
}

// unsafe, items is already dangling
b.setSharedItems(*p_items);

SharedItems& items2 = b.getItems();
```

Answer (score 5):

The code passes a reference into `setSharedItems`, but `SharedItems _items;` is NOT a reference, so `_items = items;` copies `items` into `_items`. `a._items` is different from `b._items`, so `b` will be just fine after `a` fades away. Since `b` made copies of all of the `shared_ptr`s the reference counts have not hit zero and all of the pointers will still be good.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is valid. 
You class holds the vector by value so in your setter

```
_item = item
```

Will copy the whole vector